# ¿Cómo usar "Create table" sin Hive usando SparkSQL?

Tags: maven, centos7, apache-spark, hive

Estoy intentando hacer `spark.sql("CREATE TABLE nombreTabla");`

Primero he creado la base de datos, y después he intentado hacer eso. Mi objetivo es crear una tabla sencilla y hacer inserciones sin hacer uso de HIVE en un clúster Hadoop con Spark-shell.

Según he leído, hay que añadir las dependencias de Hive, lo cual es posible sin tenerlo instalado, utilizando Maven. La historia es que estoy usando CentOS 7 en un clúster.

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE '/table'")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE '/table''(line 1, pos 22)

    == SQL ==
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE '/table'
----------------------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$2(SparkSession.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:602)
  ... 47 elided
```

También he intentado usar `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.

Mencionar que cuando hago un `CREATE DATABASE test`, el spark-warehouse y la carpeta "test" se crean correctamente.

¿Realmente necesito las dependencias? ¿Cómo las añado?